# Review my simple VBA script with built-in Excel function

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose that I have Excel file consists of four worksheets, lets name them as 1, 2, 3 and 4. I want to evaluate a sum of all values from the cells AK10, AK25, AK40 and so on till AK160 on the worksheet 4 and then place it in the cell G23 of worksheet 2.

Here is my macro that I assign to worksheet 2:

```
Sub sum_up()
Dim i As Integer, s As Integer
s = 0
For i = 0 To 10
s = WorksheetFunction.Sum(s, Worksheets("4").Range("AK(10 + 15 * i)"))
Next i
Range("G23").Value = "s"
End Sub
```

It ends up with 400 error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is your expected output?

Comment: Hmmm... No specific problem, but a quick Google of *Excel 400 error* turns up a whole bunch of hits that offer solutions. Took me about 2 seconds, knowing absolutely nothing else than what you wrote with *It ends up with 400 error*. Just a suggestion. You might also learn to read the code you write; what do you expect embedding a variable inside a string is going to do? What do you expect Excel to make of `"AK(10 + 15 * i)"` when `i` is inside the quotes?

Comment: @jmoon, I update my question. It fails with error 400. Expected output is a sum of all values in cells of the form AK(10+15*i), where i goes from 0 to 10, so it is =4!AK10+4!AK25+...+4!AK145+4!AK160.

Comment: `.Range("AK"&(10+10*i)`
to make any calculation, take it out of quotes. Inside they are read as string and no calculation is done.

Comment: Do you want to read from a _cell_ as asked in question, of a _range_ as coded?

Comment: Another issue with your code - each time to loop through it, you're assigning a new S, and removing the old one. You need to start with a S=0 outside of the loop, then your S = S + Formula is how you get it to keep incrementing

Comment: @Selkie Lots of other errors, but accumulating the sum within the variable `s` isn't one of them.  The code is `s = WorksheetFunction.Sum(s, something)` which is a (convoluted!) way of saying `s = s + something`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub sum_up()

    Dim i As Long, s As Long
    s = 0
    For i = 0 To 10
        s = s + Worksheets("4").Cells(10 + 15 * i, "AK").Value
    Next i
    Range("G23").Value = s

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a crack at this - I'd really use a lot more named ranged to pass data back and forth...:

```
Sub sum_up()
    Dim i As Integer, s As Integer
    s = 0
    For i = 0 To 10
    s = s + Worksheets("4").Range("AK" & (10 + 15 * i))
    Next I

    Range("G23").Value = s

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not say that the summation was to be done using VBA

put this in G23 on worksheet2 (actually, put this in any cell)

```
=SUM('4'!AK10,'4'!AK25,'4'!AK40,'4'!AK55,'4'!AK70,'4'!AK85,'4'!AK100,'4'!AK115,'4'!AK130,'4'!AK145,'4'!AK160)
```

as far as what you are doing wrong with your code, that has partly been answered by @KenWhite

you are also putting the letter "s" into G23 of any worksheet that happens to be visible at the time your code runs

put in a reference to sheet 2, same as you referenced sheet 4 just two lines above

this code should work:

```
Sub sum_up()

    Dim ws4 As Worksheet
    Set ws4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("4")

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws4.Range("ak10")          ' point to "ak10"

    Dim total As Long
    total = rng.Value

    Do While True
        rng.Select
        Set rng = rng.Offset(15)         ' move pointer down 15 rows

        If rng.Row > 160 Then Exit Do    ' moved past row 160 ?

        total = total + rng.Value

    Loop

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("2").Range("G23").Value = total

End Sub
```